# Error about AVX (?) when running Tensorflow

Tags: python, tensorflow

I'm attempting to do text generation with Tensorflow but whenever I run it I get this:

```
2022-08-12 19:35:08.527356: I tensorflow/core/platform/cpu_feature_guard.cc:193] This TensorFlow binary is optimized with oneAPI Deep Neural Network Library (oneDNN) to use the following CPU instructions in performance-critical operations:  AVX AVX2
To enable them in other operations, rebuild TensorFlow with the appropriate compiler flags.
2022-08-12 19:35:08.945360: I tensorflow/core/common_runtime/gpu/gpu_device.cc:1532] Created device /job:localhost/replica:0/task:0/device:GPU:0 with 6007 MB memory:  -> device: 0, name: NVIDIA GeForce RTX 2070, pci bus id: 0000:29:00.0, compute capability: 7.5

Process finished with exit code -1073740791 (0xC0000409)
```

what could be wrong?

**EDIT 1**
The code works if I only use the CPU, I've reinstalled CUDA but it didn't help.

Comment: Please provide enough code so others can better understand or reproduce the problem.

Comment: Hi @Someguy75387946, AVX is a set of CPU instructions that can improve the performance of mathematical operations used in deep learning. However, some older CPUs do not support AVX instructions, and TensorFlow may not be able to use them. I think this may be the reason you are facing this error. Thank You.